# Is there any way to handle network-caching option in flutter vlc player?

Tags: flutter, dart, video-streaming, vlc

I am streaming a video to android platform with flutter vlc player.

When I stream the video, it has delay of 2-3 seconds. However if I stream at linux_vlc_player, with setting network-caching option into 0 sec, it shows about 0.5 seconds delay. So I thought the delay in flutter vlc player also can be reduced when I handle the caching option, but I could not find it in flutter_vlc_player.

Where can I find the option?

The image below is how I handled the caching option in linux vlc player. You can see the Caching option is 0ms.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for the same. I'm trying to achieve ultra low-latency streams in Flutter, which for my application probably means switching from MJPEG to RTSP.

In the meantime though, and perhaps a good fit for your application, the flutter_mjpeg package is pretty simple to use, and doesn't cripple the latency with a long buffer:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mjpeg

Comment: I am working on similar requirements and have achieved a very low latency with the following project: https://github.com/oneeyedraven/flutter_rtsp_ffmpeg. It is still in development and requires a lot of effort to be production grade. Please see if you can help!

Comment: flutter_mpeg does not support rtsp, does it?
When I try to use it, throws error:
`Invalid argument(s): Unsupported scheme 'rtsp' in URI`

Comment: Correct, it does not. I was offering it as a temporary solution that gets decent latency performance (using mjpeg) with minimal effort.